# google ortools - exclude zeros from a set of data and figure out the square deviation

Tags: java, or-tools, cp-sat

I have a set of data, such as [0,47,52,49,55,0,46], How do I use Ortools Google JAVA Constraintsolver to exclude zeros from this set of data and figure out the square deviation of the remaining data?

Comment: Must you use that constraintSolver? Are you allowed to write a method to do that?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We’d love to help you. To improve your chances of getting an answer, here are some tips: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It shouldn't, because every piece of data in that set is not a specific value, but a range, of type IntVar